# Call self written JavaScript function from C# in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, code-behind

I need do call a self written JavaScript function from C#.

I have seen many solutions like this:

```
Page p = new Page();
     p.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "JavaScript File", 
     "functionName");
```

But nothing works for me.

What parameter do i have to put in this method?

Comment: Can you add JavaScript function on aspx page rather than storing in external file ?

Comment: If there is no other option. But the file ist really big (i use it for highcharts) and i would like it more, if it's in a single file